# Struggling with multiple npm issues one after the other

Tags: angular, npm

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@5.5.12
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   rxjs@"^5.5.8" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^5.5.0" from @angular/common@5.2.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     @angular/common@"^5.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"^5.2.0 || ^6.0.0" from ngx-toastr@8.10.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-toastr
npm ERR!       ngx-toastr@"^8.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@angular/platform-browser)
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/core)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from ngx-toastr@8.10.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-toastr
npm ERR!   ngx-toastr@"^8.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Could not understand what is the actual problem here.

Comment: Angular 5? Is your project 6 years old and never updated?

Comment: We made lots of changes but never had breaking reasons to upgrade. Others in the team doesn't have issues installing/building.

Comment: I would suggest setting up git in the project, remove the angular-app folder, globally install the latest angular (`npm i --global @angular/cli@latest`), recreate the app (`ng new xxx --style scss --routing`) and use a git client to revert the outstanding changes necessary

Answer (score 2):

You have incompatible dependencies.

Angular v5 requires RxJS v5 but `ngx-toastr@8.10.2` requires `rxjs@"^6.0.0"`.

Also your stack is totally outdated, you should update it.

Comment: I understand stack is outdated but I can't change due to funding reasons. How else can I resolve these dependency issues ? Others on the team can install and build the same app. why am I having issues ?